# Issue with reactive streams

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
q.add("1");
q.add("2");
q.add("3");

WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();

webSocketClient.execute(new URI("wss://echo.websocket.org"), session -> session
        .send(Flux.just("INIT").map(session::textMessage))
        .thenMany(session
                .send(Flux.<String>generate(sink ->
                {
                    if (q.peek() != null)
                        sink.next(q.poll());
                    else
                        sink.complete();
                }).map(session::textMessage))
        )
        .thenMany(session
                .receive()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .map(s -> "Received: " + s)
                .log()
        )
        .then())
        .subscribe();

int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    String msg = "MSG #" + i++;
    q.add(msg);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Output:

```
INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: INIT)
INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: 1)
INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: 2)
INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: 3)
INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #0)
```

And then it stops. The `while (true)` is always populating the queue. To my understanding, the way I used `thenMany` was supposed to generate a new Flux with the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` content every time the previous was marked as `complete()`. But that doesn't seems to be working.

**Edit:**
Basically what I want is to send data to the websocket from outside the lambda scope. Thats why I created a queue and used `.thenMany(session.send(Flux.<String>generate.....` I expected that it would keep reading from the queue while other threads add data to it.

Comment: i have edit the solution below

Comment: Is it possible the `sink.complete();` executes before any new messages go into the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you combine sending and receiving with [`thenMany`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#thenMany-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) method on `Mono` and `Flux`.
`thenMany` method makes `Flux` ignore element from this flux and react only on completion signal.

So, nothing happens unless you call `sink.complete()`. 
But after calling [`complete`](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.3-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html?is-external=true#onComplete()) method no further events will be sent even if requested.

Sending and receiving should be made independent.

Also, instead of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` a [`FluxProcessor`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processor-overview) and `FluxSink` can be used.
`EmitterProcessor` can emit to several subscribers while honoring backpressure for each of its subscribers. When it has no subscriber, it can still accept a few data pushes up to a configurable `bufferSize`.

```
int bufferSize = 10;
FluxProcessor<String, String> processor =
    EmitterProcessor.<String>create(bufferSize).serialize();
FluxSink<String> sink = processor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);

sink.next("1");
sink.next("2");
sink.next("3");

WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
webSocketClient.execute(new URI("wss://echo.websocket.org"),
    session -> {
      Flux<WebSocketMessage> out = Flux.just("INIT")
          .concatWith(processor)
          .map(session::textMessage);

      session.send(out)
          .subscribe(); //instead of thenMany

      return session.receive()
          .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
          .map(s -> "Received: " + s)
          .log()
          .then();
    })
    .subscribe();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  sink.next("MSG #" + i);
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}
sink.complete();
```

Logs:

```
17:57:54.177 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
17:57:54.178 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - request(unbounded)
17:57:54.304 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: INIT)
17:57:54.305 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: 1)
17:57:54.305 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: 2)
17:57:54.306 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: 3)
17:57:54.307 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #1)
17:57:54.396 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #2)
17:57:55.454 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #3)
17:57:56.480 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #4)
17:57:57.505 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #5)
17:57:58.412 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #6)
17:57:59.448 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #7)
17:58:00.484 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #8)
17:58:01.496 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #9)
17:58:02.434 [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO reactor.Flux.Map.1 - onNext(Received: MSG #10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see you are searching for a queue that always emit the data that come to.
so im suggesting you to use WebFlux Processor and to separate send and receive in 2 different streams ;

```
    EmitterProcessor<String> e = EmitterProcessor.create();
    e.onNext("1");

    WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();



    webSocketClient.execute(new java.net.URI("wss://echo.websocket.org"), webSocketSession -> {
        return    Mono.zip( listenData(webSocketSession),
                sendSms(webSocketSession,e),(aVoid, aVoid2) -> aVoid);

    }).subscribe();



    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        String msg = "MSG #" + i++;

        e.onNext(msg);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }


 private Mono<Void> sendSms(WebSocketSession webSocketSession,EmitterProcessor<String> e) {
   return webSocketSession.send(e.map(webSocketSession::textMessage).log());
}

private Mono<Void> listenData(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
    return webSocketSession
            .receive()
            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
            .map(s -> "Received: " + s)
            .log()
            .then();
}
```

Comment: `.thenMany(session.send(Flux.from(emitterProcessor))` also doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you give an example with simple data what do you want to achieve and where is the problems. So maybe i can help you. @1nt3rn3t

Comment: I want to send data to the websocket from outside the lambda scope. Thats why I created a queue and used `.thenMany(session.send(Flux.<String>generate....`. I expected that it would keep reading from the queue while other threads add data to it.

Comment: Hi @1nt3rn3t thank you for the explanation i got the problem and i have edited my response. Can you please test it. it seems to work ok.